Swagger config for Jersey + Spring boot application
I have application to build rest apis with jersey and spring boot for auto configuration. I am trying to add swagger documentation for my apis. Below is my build.gradle
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey'
    implementation 'org.apache.groovy:groovy'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.ext/jersey-bean-validation
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-bean-validation:3.1.5'

    implementation 'io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-jaxrs2-jakarta:2.2.21'
}

and JeseryConfig
@Configuration
class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public JerseyConfig() {
        packages("com.example.demo");
        register(OpenApiResource.class);
   }
}

I am able to access the openapi json at
localhost:8080/openapi.json

But I need swagger-ui as well. Can someone help me on configuring swagger-ui? I tried with implementation 'org.webjars:swagger-ui:5.17.2' for UI, but it didn't worked, did I missed any config for UI?
